# Solving the exponential equation $4^x - 10 \cdot 4^{-x} = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was gliding through some problems using substitution like my book was using and I ran into this problem. I'm not quite sure where to start with it.

> $$4^x - 10 \cdot 4^{-x} = 3$$

What would be the process you solve this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Multiplying through by $4^x$ gives the equivalent equation
$$(4^x)^2 - 10 = 3 (4^x).$$
If we write $4^x$ as $u$ and rearrange, we get the quadratic equation
$$u^2 - 3 u - 10 = 0$$
in $u$. (NB even though this gives two solutions in $u$, there is only one solution $x$ to the original equation, for reasons that become apparent while carrying out the algebra.)

Comment: Ah! I can't believe I overlooked that, Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful! NB the same trick can be used to solve, e.g., trinomial equations of the form $a x^{2m} + b x^m + c = 0$.